# AJAX and proxy: loading foreign website with another query?

Tags: php, ajax, query-string

so that's a weird thing i'm working on. 
some of you already helped me with this script:

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
 # Get the Referred URL
  $raw = file_get_contents( $_GET['url'] );
 # RegExp to Strip All Script tags and/or links with Javascript in them.
  $safe = preg_replace( '/<script[^>]*>.*<\/script>|[\"\']javascript:.*[\"\']/im' , '' , $raw );
  echo $safe;
} else {
  echo 'No URL Set';
}
```

it's a proxy which lets me use the jquery load method with  `proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.somedomain.com/`

that works perfectly. i wonder now if i can pass along ANOTHER query string in that url which http://www.somedomain.com can $_GET from the url?

I think that might me hard to understand what i'm after.
i wonder if it's somehow possible to do that:
`proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.somedomain.com&query=anewquerywhichsomedomaincanread`

if i set another ? as query it ends in a 404 because i can't set two ? in an url.
`proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.somedomain.com?query=anewquerywhichsomedomaincanread`

so i wonder if theres a trick in doing that so somedomain.com can use the $_GET method to get the second query string from the url. I can't use an & because:
this -> `proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.somedomain.com&query=anewquerywhichsomedomaincanread`
would actually look like this -> `http://www.somedomain.com&query=anewquerywhichsomedomaincanread` for somedomain.com.

do you get me? any ideas?

Comment: This is a major security hazard and an open invitation to cross-site scripting. I'd highly recommend you find some other way to do what you're trying to do, other than blindly outputting the HTML of another page into your own page. Your regular expression does not and cannot prevent JavaScript being inserted into your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to URI encode the entire URL you're passing in the query string. You can use [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) in JavaScript to do so.

Comment: thank you for the tipp but i don't get it quite. so how this work? I'll use the whole uri-string with two ? in it and encode it! and than i'll decode it on the server side to get the value?

$sv.load(http://www.mydomain.com/proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.anydomain.com/some.php?=querystring);

Comment: You should apply URI encoding to the whole URL you're trying to retrieve, like this: h t t p ://www.example.com/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.remote.com%2F%3Ffoo%3Dbar

Comment: and how do i then get the information (query) out there in my www.remothe.com site?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean how to decode the URL? If so, you probably don't have to. Most platforms will automatically decode it for you. So both the proxy as well as the URL you're requesting through the proxy should work right out of the box.